# How to programmatically show the Android status bar?

Tags: android, hide, show, statusbar, expand

Is there a way to show the android status bar when it's hidden from a service? By show I mean just the bar on the top of the screen, not expanding the notification area.

Smart Statusbar in the play store somehow does this without root.

In addition, I have also tried to expand the status bar notification with the following code:

```
Object service = mContext.getSystemService("statusbar");
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
Method expand = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
expand.invoke(service);
```

With the required permissions. But nothing seemed to happen.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which context are you storing in mContext? Better use `getApplicationContext()` here;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a JB limitation. If the app is fullscreen, the original method can not expand the status bar.